# SQL: max(date) returns wrong matching column

Tags: mysql, sql

IF I run below query

```
select prod_id, date, price 
from product_price;
```

I get these correct results:

```
3  2011-02-25 14:30:24   24000

3  2013-04-12 15:58:40   28000

3  2011-04-01 00:00:00   25000

3  2012-04-13 14:53:01   26500

3  2012-05-08 12:31:01   26500
```

But when I would like to get back a row with the max date with matching price, I do get back the max date column, BUT with the wrong price (24000 column), which should be  actually 28000

SQL I've tried

```
select max(date), price from product_price group by prod_id;

select max(date), price 
from product_price 
group by prod_id having max(date);
```

Both sql returns the below wrong price result:

```
3  2013-04-12 15:58:40   24000
```

I should in fact get.

```
3  2013-04-12 15:58:40   28000
```

Any idea how to get back the matching price with the max date?

Thanks
Nic

Comment: It's only because MySQL doesn't follow the SQL standard that it even processes those queries. Consider a table containing two rows with excatly the same `date` value (and that happens to be the maximum value) but different `price` values - what value should be in the result set then?

Answer (score 2):

You can `ORDER BY date DESC` with `LIMIT 1` to get the `prod_id` with the max date, like this:

```
SELECT prod_id, date, price
FROM product_price
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

See it in action here:

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19a0d/2)